# KnockoutJS IE issue

Tags: internet-explorer, knockout.js

Can someone please help me with this?

Basically I have a list of items with child items. When an item is checked (checkbox) I have a bindingHandlers that automatically checks matching items and ticks the checkboxes.

This works all fine with Chrome, FF and IE > 9 but not with IE 7 or 8. When a checkbox is ticked it remains unticked and the ones automatically ticked by the bindingHandlers cannot be unticked.

My second question is how can I set isDirty flag to child items as the child (e.g: **Lines** in my data example) items are mapped to a form. Is this possible?

Sorry, wanted to post the code in jsfiddle.net but couldn't get it to work :(

Also, is there better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I've managed to put the code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/huzzi786/ugcJU/

**All I'm trying to do is when a checkbox is checked (only checked) find matching items  based on some conditions and mark them checked then display the child item on the form that works with IE 7. It would be bonus to get the isDirty flag working on the child items.**

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Id</td>
                        <td>Name</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: users">
                    <tr data-bind="attr: { id: ('user-' + id()) }">
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: id(), id: id() }, checked: isSelected, SelectRelatedUsers: Name, event:{'change' : $parent.selectUser }" /></td>
                        <td class="quiet"><span data-bind="text: id"></span></td>
                        <td class="quiet">
                            <a href="#" class="tag-ts" data-bind="text: Name, click: $parent.selectUser"></a>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">


            <table data-bind="with: selectedUser, visible: selectedUser() !=null" style="border: 1px solid #ccc">

                <thead>
                    <th>Day</th>
                    <th>isDirty</th>

                </thead>

                <tbody data-bind="foreach: Lines">

                    <tr>
                        <td>Mon</td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="input-small" type="text" data-bind="value: Mon" />
                        </td>
                  <!--       <td data-bind="text: dirtyFlag.isDirty() ? 'Yes' : 'No'"> -->
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tue</td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="input-small" type="text" data-bind="value: Tue" />
                        </td>
                         <!--  <td data-bind="text: dirtyFlag.isDirty() ? 'Yes' : 'No'"> -->
                        <tr>
                            <td>Wed</td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="input-small" type="text" data-bind="value: Wed" />
                            </td>
                             <!--  <td data-bind="text: dirtyFlag.isDirty() ? 'Yes' : 'No'"> -->
                            <tr>
                                <td>Thu</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input class="input-small" type="text" data-bind="value: Thu" />
                                </td>
                           <!--     <td data-bind="text: dirtyFlag.isDirty() ? 'Yes' : 'No'"> -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Fri</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input class="input-small" type="text" data-bind="value: Fri" />
                                    </td>
                                  <!--    <td data-bind="text: dirtyFlag.isDirty() ? 'Yes' : 'No'"> -->
                                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <button type="button" data-bind="click: saveData">
                                Save
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

**KnockoutJS**

```
 ko.dirtyFlag = function (root, isInitiallyDirty) {
        var result = function () { }
        var _initialState = ko.observable(ko.toJSON(root));
        var _isInitiallyDirty = ko.observable(isInitiallyDirty);

        result.isDirty = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            return _isInitiallyDirty() || _initialState() !== ko.toJSON(root);
        });

        result.reset = function () {
            _initialState(ko.toJSON(root));
            _isInitiallyDirty(false);
        };

        return result;
    };

    var userMapping = {
        users: {
            key: function (item) {
                return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.Id);
            },
            create: function (options) {
                return createUser(options.data);
            }
        }
    };

    var createUser = function (user) {
        var result = ko.mapping.fromJS(user);
        result.dirtyFlag = ko.dirtyFlag(result);
        return result;
    };



        ViewModel = function (serverData) {
            users = ko.observableArray();
            selectedUser = ko.observable();
            selectedLines = ko.observable();
            users(serverData.users());

            ko.bindingHandlers.SelectRelatedUsers = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                },
                update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

                    var u = (bindingContext.$parent.users);
                    // console.log(u.length)
                    if ($(element).is(':checked')) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < u().length; i++) {
                            if ((viewModel.group() == u()[i].group()) && (viewModel.status() == u()[i].status()) && (viewModel.accesslevel() == u()[i].accesslevel())) {
                                u()[i].isSelected(true);

                            } else {
                                u()[i].isSelected(false);

                            }
                        };
                    }
                }
            };

            selectUser = function () {
                selectedUser(this);
                selectedLines(this.Lines);
                console.log(selectedLines)
            };


            saveData = function () {
                alert('Saving data...')
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/server/save",
                    data: ko.toJSON(selectedLines()),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('div-result').show();
                    }
                });

            };

            return {
                users: users,
                saveData: saveData,
                selectUser: selectUser

            }

        };

        var getdata = ko.mapping.fromJSON('{"users":[{"id":1,"Name":"Ali","group":2,"status":false,"accesslevel":1,"isSelected":false,"Lines":[{"lineid":3,"Mon":1,"Tue":8,"Wed":3,"Thu":4,"Fri":5}]},{"id":2,"Name":"Patel","group":2,"status":false,"accesslevel":1,"isSelected":false,"Lines":[{"lineid":2,"Mon":4,"Tue":2,"Wed":4,"Thu":4,"Fri":5}]},{"id":3,"Name":"Peter","group":2,"status":false,"accesslevel":2,"isSelected":false,"Lines":[{"lineid":3,"Mon":1,"Tue":11,"Wed":3,"Thu":1,"Fri":5}]},{"id":4,"Name":"Martin","group":2,"status":false,"accesslevel":2,"isSelected":false,"Lines":[{"lineid":4,"Mon":11,"Tue":2,"Wed":13,"Thu":4,"Fri":5}]},{"id":5,"Name":"Terry","group":2,"status":false,"accesslevel":2,"isSelected":false,"Lines":[{"lineid":5,"Mon":1,"Tue":2,"Wed":3,"Thu":4,"Fri":5}]}]}', userMapping, {});

        ko.applyBindings(ViewModel(getdata));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is related in some way to the order that events are fired in IE.

You can overcome this by returning true from your `selectUser` function, which allows the default action to be performed.

So, you would want to change it to:

```
        selectUser = function () {
            selectedUser(this);
            selectedLines(this.Lines);
            return true;
        };
```

Comment: That works thank you :) How can I put isDirty to a child items? Also, is there a better way of selecting related users as the way I'm doing seems bit heavy as I need to loop through all the records. Thanks again.

Comment: Looks like you are adding the dirtyFlag properly.  It is including the "isSelected" flag though, so things become dirty when they are selected.